# Converting downstem shifters to barcons

Tags: gears, shifter, diy

What considerations should be made for converting a downstem shifting system to barcons? Both the current system and the system that I would like are friction shifters.

The bike is a 1986 Peugeot Iseran 10-speed.

Thanks and be well.

Comment: Downstem or downtube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are both friction shift sets, there is no conversion necessary. Just new cables, and placing the new shifters on the bar before routing the new cables.

Difficulty might be finding good quality friction shifters to begin with, but there's nothing complicated about the changeover.

Comment: Thanks very much for the information. I am going to go with some NOS Suntour barcons as most new barcons have at least one indexed shifter.

Comment: @CurtisEdwardFranklin a lot of those indexed barcons can be switched to non-indexed.

Comment: I'm using the Shimano BS-SL77 baron shifters on my touring bike. The front shifter is friction, and the rear shifter can be switched between indexed and friction.

Comment: @freiheit While that is true, the cost of a new set is very expensive. I have roughly sourced NOS Suntour bar end shifters for about half the price. If I can't close a deal on the vintage shifters, then I will look into those BS-SL77.

Answer (score 1):

According to the '86 Peugeot catalog you're dealing with stem shifters. You should have cable stops on the downtube. You will use those. Measure your handlebar inside diameter to ensure you can find barcons that will fit. If it's not standardized, get a new handlebar.